# Member creation (backend) - doing anything but setting username first causes validation errors

Tags: visitor

When I create a user in the backend, the Member Group comes first, and is the obvious place to start. However, if I choose a Member Group before adding an Email (email is username in my case), the form throws an error - "The screen name you chose is not available".

Adding an Email is not enough to clear the error - I need to select a different Member Group (before re-selecting the Member Group I originally wanted). This seems like a bug to me, but is there anything I can do to alter the behaviour of the form? It's causing confusion among my users, and is not user friendly at all.

Visitor 3.0.1,
EE 3.5.12

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is a bug, You should contact Visitor to give you support regarding this.

For a quick fix, You can edit the Visitor module and comment this lines. It will solve your issue for now.

```
if (ee()->session->ban_check('screen_name', $data['screen_name']) OR trim(preg_replace("/&nbsp;*/", '', $data['screen_name'])) == '') {
    return lang('v:screen_name_taken');
}
```

Comment: I have indeed raised a call. Thank you, that quick fix seems to work. For reference, the code begins in ft.visitor.php, line 551.